# In Doctor Sleep, why can ghosts overpower Rose the Hat?

Tags: doctor-sleep

I only watched the movie *Dr. Sleep* and don't quite understand how "shine" works. From what I saw, Danny is able to box those ghosts, and Rose can easily destroy the box even when Danny has Abra's help. Physically, she can tank through Dan's axe and retaliate, so how is that female ghost able to knock down Rose singlehandedly before other ghosts gang up on her?

Comment: I would have to watch the film version again and then look for a source, but I believe it's because the ghosts at Overlook (where "The Shinning" takes place) have been "starving" in Danny's mind for a long time, making them altogether more powerful. Then her hat is burned in the fire...

Comment: I read through overlook hotel on villain's wiki. It seems to me the ghosts became more active from feeding on young Danny's energy, so it's unlikely that they gain power from being starving. Perhaps the authors do have an explanation and they just didn't publish it. But I'm just so fascinated about the ghosts there...